# How to fire an asynchronous task, but wait for all callbacks before returning ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, asynccallback

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 action method which accepts a `HttpFileCollectionBase` in the HTTP POST.

In this method, i need to resize and upload the image 3 times.

The action method currently looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ChangeProfilePicture()
{
   var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];

   ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Original);
   ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Profile);
   ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Thumb);

   return Content("Success", "text/plain");   
}
```

Basically this is a user profile page, where they change their profile pic. The upload happens via jQuery AJAX.

Now, how can i fire off the three `ResizeAndUpload` calls as asynchronous tasks, but not return the action result until all three tasks have completed?

Previously i've been using `Task.Factory.StartNew` to fire off asynchronous tasks, but that was when i didn't care about waiting for the result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple way of doing it, is using Join:

```
public ActionResult ChangeProfilePicture()
{
   var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
   var threads = new Thread[3];
   threads[0] = new Thread(()=>ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Original));
   threads[1] = new Thread(()=>ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Profile));
   threads[2] = new Thread(()=>ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Thumb));

   threads[0].Start();
   threads[1].Start();
   threads[2].Start();

   threads[0].Join();
   threads[1].Join();
   threads[2].Join();

   return Content("Success", "text/plain");   
}
```

It's possible though that the ResizeAndUpload method may be blocking somewhere (can't tell for sure without seeing the code) in which case it may be worthwhile to refactor those as well to make them async.

Comment: Resize and Upload does 2 things: 1) resize image using GDI, 2) upload image to Amazon. The GDI stuff is fast, it's the Amazon upload that takes a while (around 10 secs for a 2 mb file). So that's why im wanting to do them asyncronously. So there is no blocking, it's just the S3 server upload lag.

Comment: The code that uploads to Amazon, is that asynchronous? If it isn't then those three threads will just sit there and be blocked while waiting for Amazon's response. That's no good especially if this Action can be called concurrently by multiple requests. See if you can turn those calls into Async calls. It may complicate things a bit, but well worth it....

Comment: yep, the amazon upload is synchronous. But i want to wait for it because i want to refresh the user's profile pic once it's uploaded, using client-side scripting. Of course, the alternative is to make the upload async without caring about callback, and just have a message saying "Your upload has been queued for processing", etc

Comment: @RPM1984 @BFree asked if the Amazon upload was *a*synchronous :) As long as it is synchronous (i.e. blocking) then this Thread.Join() style should do exactly what you need.

Comment: @Jedidja -yes i know he asked if it's asynchronous, and i should have said "Nope, it's synchronous". I shouldn't have said "Yep". :) Anyway this works nicely, and i changed the async task to only make the upload async, so it returns to the client immediately and the photo is refreshed in due time. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

Also got it working using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, similar to @BFree's answer:

```
public ActionResult ChangeProfilePicture()
{
   var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
   var threads = new Task[3];
   threads[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Original));
   threads[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Profile));
   threads[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Thumb));

   Task.WaitAll(threads, 120000); // wait for 2mins.

   return Content("Success", "text/plain");   
}
```

Now sure if `Thread` or `Task` is better.

Comment: I think @Bfree's answer using Join() is probably better since it doesn't depend on an arbitrary wait time (e.g. 2mins)

Comment: @Jedidja - that's an optional param which i can leave out.

Answer (score 1):

Different implementation that uses Task and ManualResetEvent

```
public ActionResult Sample()
    {
        var wh1 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var wh2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var wh3 = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>(wh =>
        {
            // DoSomething();
            var handle = (ManualResetEvent)wh;
            handle.Set();
        }), wh1);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>(wh =>
        {
            // DoSomething();
            var handle = (ManualResetEvent)wh;
            handle.Set();
        }), wh2);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>(wh =>
        {
            // DoSomething();
            var handle = (ManualResetEvent)wh;
            handle.Set();
        }), wh3);

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(new[] { wh1, wh2, wh3 });

        return View();
    }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn't that basically the same as my answer below, but with more boiler plate code?

Comment: Yes, but it is different in that you have control of when you release the task from blocking

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it, use a handy "Task.WaitAll" static method for waits..

```
public MyViewModel LoadData()
{
    MyViewModel viewModel = null;

    try
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
               var task1 = Task<MyViewModel>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               {
                   return BuildMyViewModel(args);
               });

               var task2 = Task<ViewModel2>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               {
                   return BuildViewModel2(args);
               });

               var task3 = Task<ViewModel3>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               {
                   return BuildViewModel3(args);
               });

               Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);

               viewModel = task1.Result;

               viewModel.ViewModel2 = task2.Result;
               viewModel.ViewModel3 = task3.Result;

           }).Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace); 
        // ...
    }

    return viewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an async pattern for MVC actions, see this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

you can still use Tasks, but don't need any special handling to allow the actions to execute async

Comment: But the thing is, i don't want the `client->myserver` call to be asynchronous, i want the `myserver->amazon` call to be ascynhronous.

Comment: gotcha. another option is using 3 Task instances along with 3 WaitHandles, such as ManualResetEvent. I will post another answer with this code sample

Answer (score 0):

You could make up a task, with child tasks. The parent task will complete, when all child tasks have completed.

Example:

```
public ActionResult ChangeProfilePicture()
{
    var fileUpload = Request.Files[0];

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Original), 
            TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Profile), 
            TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            ResizeAndUpload(fileUpload.InputStream, Size.Thumb), 
            TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    }).Wait();

    return Content("Success", "text/plain");
}
```